# How should I handle multiple seperate batch email 'streams'?

Tags: php, email, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing

I have the following (simplified) batch email process set up under a Windows Server:

- User performs action that requires an email be sent;
- The data necessary to create the email is inserted into an SQL Server table;
- Once every 6 hours, Task Scheduler calls a PHP file which goes through the table, creating and sending out each of the outstanding emails.

This works quite well, however the application owners would like certain sorts of email sent out more regularly, in this case, every 20 minutes.

My first thought was to set up another Task Scheduler entry, but that raises the issue of what happens every 6th hour, when both tasks will be run at the same time. It will also require creating another PHP file, which isn't really a problem, but is annoying.

The other alternative I considered was to set the scheduler to every 20 minutes, and incorporate the 'what do I send, and when' logic into the batch file itself - if it's 12AM, 6AM, 12PM or 6PM perform both sets of emails, otherwise just perform the 20 minute one. That does, however, require hardcoding those times, and doesn't seem like it should be the first resort.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest to introduce some sort of severity to your messages in the sql table. Basically, you can run your scheduler every 5 minutes or so and just decide by the kind of severity which emails to deliver. Additional you can introduce another table, where the times like 20min or 6 hours for every severity is stored.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller That is essentially what I want to do, yes. It's the 'just decide' part that is the problem. Am I stuck with having to put in 'if it's 6PM deliver these', 'if it's X:20/X:40/X:00 deliver those'? Or is there some other way of telling the program when to send certain email groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it a little bit more, I realised that I could accomplish what I wanted via the application of the PHP time() function and some modulo arithmetic:

```
$runTime = time();                //Set time the program was run, seconds since epoch
$modTimeHour = $runTime % 3600;   //3600 seconds in an hour
$modTimeTwenty = $runTime % 1200; //1200 seconds in twenty minutes

//Task Scheduler doesn't always run exactly on the dot, so give it some leeway
if ($modTimeHour < 5 || $modTimeHour > 3595) {  
     //send emails - category 1
}

if ($modTimeTwenty < 5 || $modTimeTwenty > 1195) {
    //send emails - category 2
}
```

By getting the seconds since epoch, and checking whether the modulo of the number of seconds in the time periods I'm interested in is within a certain range, I can have many different 'streams' all going out at their proper times.